# I want to upgrade table attribute in add method, when i add something in a table i want to decrement an attribute in the other table

Tags: symfony

I have two tables, "Maison" and "Resident", when adding a resident i want to decrement the nombre of places of the table "Maison", i want u to know that i have a foreign key of table "Maison" on "Resident", and when adding a resident i have a list from where i choose which "Maison" i want to add the resident

I tried this:

```
        $nomMaison = $request->get('nom_maison');
 $maison = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Maison::class)->find($nomMaison);
 foreach ($maison as $i){

             $maison->setNbrPersonne($maison->getNbrPersonne()-1);
             $em->persist($maison);
             $em->flush();
         }
```

And it didn't work

```
ResidentController.php

    public function ajoutreAction(Request $request)

    {
        $r = new Resident();
        $Form = $this->createForm(ResidentType::class, $r);
        $Form->handleRequest($request);
        $nomMaison = $request->get('nom_maison');

        if ($Form->isSubmitted()) {
           $maison = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Maison::class)->find($nomMaison);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          foreach ($maison as $i){

             $maison->setNbrPersonne($maison->getNbrPersonne()-1);
             $em->persist($maison);
             $em->flush();
         }

            $em->persist($r);
            $em->flush();


            return $this->redirectToRoute('affiche_re');


        }

        return $this->render('MaisonretraiteBundle:resident:ajoutre.html.twig', array('form' => $Form->createView()));
    }
```

```
ResidentType.php

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $sexe = array(
            'Homme' => 'Homme',
            'Femme' => 'Femme'
        );
        $alzheimer = array(
            'Oui' => 'Oui',
            'Non' => 'Non'
        );
        $builder->add('nomResident',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Nom:'))
            ->add('prenomResident',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Prénom:'))
            ->add('ageResident')
            -> add('sexeResident',ChoiceType::class,array(
              'choices'=>$sexe,
'expanded'=>true,
                'label'=>'Sexe:'
            ))

            -> add('alzheimerResident',ChoiceType::class,array(
                'choices'=> $alzheimer,
                'expanded'=>true,
                'label'=>'Alzheimer'
            ))
            ->add('maladieResident',TextareaType::class,array('label'=>'Maladie:'))
            ->add('responsable',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Responsable:'))
            ->add('telephoneResponsable',TelType::class,array('label'  => 'Numero Telephone :   '))
            ->add('maison', EntityType::class,array(
            'class'=>'MaisonretraiteBundle:Maison',
            'choice_label'=>'nom_maison',
            'multiple'=>false,
                'label'  => 'Choisissez votre maison :   '
        ))->add('dateResident',DateType::class,array('disabled'=>'true'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Maison.php

<?php

namespace MaisonretraiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SBC\NotificationsBundle\Builder\NotificationBuilder;
use SBC\NotificationsBundle\Model\NotifiableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Maison
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="maison", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_user", columns={"id_user"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Maison implements NotifiableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_maison", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idMaison;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom_maison", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nomMaison;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse_maison", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le nom est obligatoire")
     */
    private $adresseMaison;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephone_maison", type="string", length=8, nullable=false)
     */
    private $telephoneMaison;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mail_maison", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $mailMaison;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nbr_personne", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $nbrPersonne;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdMaison()
    {
        return $this->idMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $idMaison
     */
    public function setIdMaison($idMaison)
    {
        $this->idMaison = $idMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNomMaison()
    {
        return $this->nomMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nomMaison
     */
    public function setNomMaison($nomMaison)
    {
        $this->nomMaison = $nomMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdresseMaison()
    {
        return $this->adresseMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $adresseMaison
     */
    public function setAdresseMaison($adresseMaison)
    {
        $this->adresseMaison = $adresseMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTelephoneMaison()
    {
        return $this->telephoneMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $telephoneMaison
     */
    public function setTelephoneMaison($telephoneMaison)
    {
        $this->telephoneMaison = $telephoneMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMailMaison()
    {
        return $this->mailMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $mailMaison
     */
    public function setMailMaison($mailMaison)
    {
        $this->mailMaison = $mailMaison;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getNbrPersonne()
    {
        return $this->nbrPersonne;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $nbrPersonne
     */
    public function setNbrPersonne($nbrPersonne)
    {
        $this->nbrPersonne = $nbrPersonne;
    }

    /**
     * @var \User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idUser;

    /**
     * @return \User
     */
    public function getIdUser()
    {
        return $this->idUser;
    }

    /**
     * @param \User $idUser
     */
    public function setIdUser($idUser)
    {
        $this->idUser = $idUser;
    }

    public function notificationsOnCreate(NotificationBuilder $builder)
    {
        $notification = new Notification();
        $notification
            ->setTitle('New Maison')
            ->setDescription($this->nomMaison)
            ->setRoute('affiche_ma')// I suppose you have a show route for your entity
            ->setParameters(array('id' => $this->idMaison))
        ;
        $builder->addNotification($notification);

        return $builder;    }

    public function notificationsOnUpdate(NotificationBuilder $builder)
    {
        $notification = new Notification();
        $notification
            ->setTitle('Maison updated')
            ->setDescription($this->nomMaison)
            ->setRoute('affiche_ma')
            ->setParameters(array('id' => $this->idMaison))
        ;
        $builder->addNotification($notification);

        return $builder;    }

    public function notificationsOnDelete(NotificationBuilder $builder)
    {
        // in case you don't want any notification for a special event
        // you can simply return an empty $builder
        return $builder;    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this error :

```
   $maison = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Maison::class)->find($nomMaison);
```

you must change its by this line (where name is the attribute name of the entity maison, because find($idmaison) take like param the id of the entity)

```
$maison = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Maison::class)->findOneBy(['nomMaison' => $nomMaison]); 
$id = $maison->getIdMaison();
```

you need also to change $request->get('nom_maison') by $request->query->get('nom_maison') if you use get METHOD. if you use POST you must use $request->request->get('nom_maison')

Comment: you need also to change $request->get('nom_maison') by $request->query->get('nom_maison') if you use get METHOD. if you use POST you must use $request->request->get('nom_maison')

Comment: you can show me the error that you have ? i need also the know the version of symfony that you use ?

Comment: the version is symfony 3.4,

Comment: the problem is that when i add a resident, i have a list of Maison name not the id of Maison(which is the foreign key)

Comment: it s like im affecting a resident to a house, im doing that by selecting the name of the house from a list, but when i  want to increment the nbr of places of the house, i cant, because im working with the name of the house not the id(which is the foreign key)

Comment: so you can get the id by name like that      $maison = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Maison::class)->findOneBy(['name' => $nomMaison]); $id = $maison->getId();

Comment: i got an error: Unrecognized field: name
on finByOne

Comment: you must use the attribute name of house of your entity  maison . i think you used nom_maison

Comment: so you put : ->findOneBy(['nom_maison' => $nomMaison]);

Comment: the same problem :(

Comment: i posted it now, check it

Comment: $maison = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Maison::class)->findOneBy(['nomMaison' => $nomMaison]); $id = $maison->getId();

Comment: another error: Error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Comment: $id = $maison->getIdMaison();

Comment: Error: Call to a member function getIdMaison() on null

Comment: so you don't have a maison with the given name. try to check your database

Comment: no im sure that it exists i ll post a screen shot, when adding a resident i got a list of maison (im getting it from the database)

Comment: so the probleme come from $nomMaison . try to debug dump($nomMaison);

Comment: he s not getting $nomMaison cause i still didnt select it, check this screenshot (it contains how i add resident) https://i.stack.imgur.com/glCyX.png

Comment: i still didnt select it so that s why he s not getting null value, when i click on the button "S'inscrire" i want at the same time to add the resident to a maison and increment the nombre of places at same time

Answer (score 0):

[this is how i add a resident, the list contain the lsit of maison existing in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glCyX.png)

Comment: i think that means im not getting the name of maison in my code